# Libreoffice 5 does not start - error while loading shared libraries

Tags: libreoffice

After installation of all .deb of LibreOffice 5, failed to start any application of LibreOffice. it crashes. Using 14.04 Ubuntu.

Message

```
libreoffice5.0 javaldx: 
Could not find a Java Runtime Environment! 
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx /opt/libreoffice5.0/program/soffice.bin: 
error while loading shared libraries: 
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file
```

Comment: What error message do you have ?

Comment: libreoffice5.0 
javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx
/opt/libreoffice5.0/program/soffice.bin: error while loading shared libraries: libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such fil

Comment: So install it ...By the way: please always include error messages into your question when you have an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to install the following lib and relaunch LibreOffice :

```
sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2:i386
```

---

The missing library `libdbus-glib-1.so.2` is in the package `libdbus-glib-1-2`.

Comment: doesn't work, i think is need i386 version.

Comment: Then try :  `sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2:i386`

Comment: How can I do it using yum?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this issue with the latest libreoffice on a production machine.

```
LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 10m0(Build:2)
```

To fix:

```
sudo apt -y install libreoffice-base
```

This will install all the requirements for libreoffice including the java-jre

Answer (score 0):

```
apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2
```

This did it for me.